# Decorator function returning undefined when using promises or callbacks

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator, typescript-decorator

I am trying to create a decorator in node js to log entry and exit from a function when it is being executed for example
`Executing ServiceClass.sampleService with params 5,1`
then after execution is finished `Execution of ServiceClass.sampleService completed with success/error`

This works fine for normal functions which return number or string or array or some object literals, but when I want to decorate a function which returns promise or callback it logs details but the values are not returned where the function is invoked.

Here is my sample code :

**logger.ts** (contains decorator function)

```
export function performanceLog(target, name, descriptor) {
    const original = descriptor.value;
    if (typeof original === 'function') {
        descriptor.value = function (...args) {
            console.log(`Executing ${target.constructor.name}.${name} with parameters ${args}`);
            // Execute function like a function with promise
            let start: any = new Date();
            return original.apply(this, args).then(data => {
                let end: any = new Date();
                end = end-start;
                console.log(`\nExecution of ${target.constructor.name}.${name} completed successfully in ${end / 1000} seconds`);
            }).catch(error => {
                let end: any = new Date();
                end = end-start;
                console.log(`\nExecution of ${target.constructor.name}.${name} completed with error in ${end / 1000} seconds`);
            });
        }
    }
    return descriptor;
}
```

**sampleService.ts** (Regular Service class)

```
import { performanceLog } from '../utilities/logger';

let err = false;
export default class SampleService {
    @performanceLog
    public sum(a, b) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(a - b);
            } else {
                resolve(a + b);
            }
        })
    }
}

const e = new SampleService();
e.sum(51, 6).then(data => console.log("## Data: ", data)).catch(err => console.log("##err: ", err));
// Here data is undefined and it never goes into the catch part either
```

What am I missing here?

**EDIT**

The similar problem exits when I have a function returning callback function

```
export default class SampleService {
    @performanceLog
    public sum(a, b, callback) {
        // return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (err) {
            return callback(a - b, null);
        } else {
            return callback(null, a+b);
        }
        // })
    }
}

const e = new SampleService();
// e.sum(51, 6).then(data => console.log("## Data: ", data)).catch(err => console.log("##err: ", err));

e.sum(51, 6, function (err, res) {
    console.log(`This is err  ${err} and res ${res}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are overriding the `Promise` value. The value returned in `then` or `catch` is propagated to the rest of the Promise chain.

If you just want to "spy" on the `Promise` then `return`/`throw` the value or don't return a new `Promise`. Example :

```
const promise = original.apply(this, args)

promise.then(data => {
    let end: any = new Date();
    end = end-start;
    console.log(`\nExecution of ${target.constructor.name}.${name} completed successfully in ${end / 1000} seconds`);
}).catch(error => {
    let end: any = new Date();
    end = end-start;
    console.log(`\nExecution of ${target.constructor.name}.${name} completed with error in ${end / 1000} seconds`);
});

return promise
```

OR

```
return original.apply(this, args).then(data => {
    let end: any = new Date();
    end = end-start;
    console.log(`\nExecution of ${target.constructor.name}.${name} completed successfully in ${end / 1000} seconds`);

    // propagate the return value
    return data;
}).catch(error => {
    let end: any = new Date();
    end = end-start;
    console.log(`\nExecution of ${target.constructor.name}.${name} completed with error in ${end / 1000} seconds`);

    // propagate the error value
    throw error
});
```

Comment: Thanks, your first one seems a cleaner approach it worked. But again I can not store a callback (ia a function returns one) in a variable using this method, because it'll always have undefined

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, do you mean in the case where the decorated function returns a function?

Comment: it is simple error first callback function and I am always expecting it as the last param. I tried to promisify it and then return it but that prints absolutely nothing

Comment: Use `Promise.resolve(original.apply(this, args))`. If `original.apply(this, args)` is a `Promise` it'll return it, else it returns a resolved promise with the value. But it'll not wait for `callback` to be called, that's another problem 

Comment: oh it is a problem  now that I set a timeout to check it's effects

Comment: For this it really depends on how you want to handle it. You can pass decorators to parameters to do something like (only available on classes I think, not sure) : `myFn(param, @Callback callback)`

Comment: Ah the thing is I am not allowed to touch functions all I can do is create decorators without making change to existing ones, here most of are either promise ones or error first callbacks

Answer (score 1):

You said it yourself, the values are not returned when the function is invoked :-) 
You are executing the original promise in the `performanceLog` decorator, and then do your performance measuring in the `then` callback. Here you pass the value from the original function, but don't return to the outside. Imagine your Promise callstack to be something like this:

```
sum(51,6)
  .then(yourPromiseLog)
  .then(theCallbackFromOutside)
```

The solution is to return the value in your decorator again:

```
return original.apply(this, args).then(data => {
  let end: any = new Date();
  end = end-start;
  console.log(`\nExecution of ${target.constructor.name}.${name} completed successfully in ${end / 1000} seconds`);
  return data;
})
```

Similarly, you have to throw the error again in the catch callback:

```
catch(error => {
  let end: any = new Date();
  end = end-start;
  console.log(`\nExecution of ${target.constructor.name}.${name} completed with error in ${end / 1000} seconds`);
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, the callstack kind of cleared the idea :)